# Change page order in PDF-file

Tags: pdf, gui

I want to select a few pages from a PDF-file, reorder them and make a new PDF-file from that.

I want a visual tool, so I can see the pages I select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [pdfarranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger).

You can select individual pages or groups. It can also rotate pages.

[image: pdfarranger]